# ¿Cómo obtengo la hora en la que se ejecuto en método?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un método **LogErrores** que permite registrar en una tabla los errores de otros métodos como por ejemplo el método **IniciarSesion** cuando los datos de ingreso son incorrectos o nulos,el método guarda los datos del usuario, la hora a la que inicio la ejecución del método y a la hora en la que sucedió el error.
Actualmente estoy usando `DateTime FechaLlamado = DateTime.Now;` en el inicio de cada método que pueda tener errores, para guardar la hora de inicio pero quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de llamar la hora a la que si inicio el método sin tener que declararla de esa manera al inicio de todos los métodos.

Answer (score 1):

La unica forma que se me ocurre hacer algo similar a lo que planteas es aplicando conceptos de `AOP (Programacion Orientada a Aspectos)`, con estas librerias podrias poner atributos en los metodo o clases que realices acciones `pre` y `post` la ejecucion de una funcionalidad

La mas conocida es

[PostSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PostSharp/)

Pero tambien podrias crear algo tu desde codigo si usa `delegates`

```
public class LogExecution{

    public static void Log(Action action){

          //aqui logueas la ejecucion

          action(); //se ejecuta el metodo

          //aqui si necesitas puede agregar un log post ejecucion
    }

}

public void Metodo1(){
   //codigo
}

public void Metodo2(){
   //codigo
}
```

Entonces lo usas

```
 LogExecution.Log(Metodo1);
 LogExecution.Log(Metodo2);
```

en este caso al usar un `Action` no retorna nada como respuesta y no defini parametros, pero se podrian aplicar si fuera necesario, para eso cambiarias a un `Func<>`

La idea es que los metodo 1 y 2 no tengan codigo de log de su ejecucion, sino que sea algo que se ejecuta por fuera previamente, algo asi aplica las librerias de `AOP`

[Action Delegate](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.5)

[Func Delegate](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=netframework-4.5)